# XPath does not return text in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, rexml

My code:

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'rexml/xpath'

doc = REXML::Document.new(response)
REXML::XPath.each(doc, "*//categoryName") { |element| puts element.text }
```

What I want this to return is the text element inside the  tag... what it actually returns is:

```
<categoryName> ... </>
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: show us the `xml` content.

Answer (score 0):

For me with a sample example works fine :

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'rexml/xpath'

doc = REXML::Document.new("<p>some text <b>this is bold!</b> more text</p>")
REXML::XPath.each(doc, "*//b") { |element| puts element.text }
# >> this is bold!
```

---

See another example ;

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'rexml/xpath'

str = <<-eot
<version>
  <locale name="en-US">
    <title>This is the Title</title>
    <description>this is the description</description>
    <keywords>
      <keyword>this</keyword>
      <keyword>that</keyword>
      <keyword>the other</keyword>
    </keywords>
  </locale>
</version>
eot
doc = REXML::Document.new(str)
REXML::XPath.each(doc, "//title") { |element| puts element.text }
REXML::XPath.each(doc, "//keyword") { |element| puts element.text }
# >> This is the Title
# >> this
# >> that
# >> the other
```